# How does == work and what does it do internally .NET

Tags: .net, equality

Here is my sample code.

```
string a = "test";

object c = a;

Console.WriteLine(a == c);

Console.WriteLine(object.Equals(a, c));

Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(c));

Console.WriteLine(c.Equals(a));
```

In this case the output is as follows

```
True
True
True
True
```

Here is another sample of code

```
string a = "test";

string b = "te";

object c = b + "st";

Console.WriteLine(a == c);

Console.WriteLine(object.Equals(a, c));

Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(c));

Console.WriteLine(c.Equals(a));
```

Now this case is a little bit more interesting because the output is this

```
False
True
True
True
```

and this really got me and made me ask myself the question, how does `==` compare two objects ? I search for the answer but I could not find anything that could explain this? Can anyone explain this. This was executed on machine with .NET 4.5.1

Comment: Hint: `==` is overloaded for `string`. So if both operands are `string` (the compile-time type of the operand, not the execution-time type) it will call the overload, which checks for string equality rather than reference equality.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs#673) and [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs). That's about as internal as it gets.

Comment: Extending what @JonSkeet said: if you declare `c` as a `string`, or cast it to a string (`a == (string)c`) then the comparison will return `true`. This is a behaviour specific to `string` (and very few other types) that is a consequence of `string` being an immutable class (as opposed to a value type).

Comment: Okay, but how do you explain that, in both cases object c refers to the same "test" literal string which in both cases is interned and if my knowledge is correct string a and object c in both cases should have a reference to literal string "test"

Comment: in first case == returned true, but in the second case though it returned false, even though it referred to the same "test" literal

Comment: See my answer for the reasoning around string interning and reference comparisons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reference types, by default, `==` is a reference comparer. As Jon Skeet pointed out in his comment, `string` overrides this behaviour so it can provide value-matching semantics. That is, the scenario you are attempting will work where both variables are of type `string`. The fact that `c` is typed as `object` means that the overload of `==` isn't used, though.

The strings are different references, despite what you may think about interning, because string interning only happens at compile time by default. At runtime, strings are only interned if you call `string.Intern` manually, and your `c` is only known at runtime (the compiler can't optimise for it). So, this snippet uses string interning manually and makes the code behave the way you hoped for:

```
string a = "test";
string b = "te";
object c = string.Intern(b + "st");
// c == a is true
```

(The last line looks up the interned version of the string, and returns that instance instead of creating a new one.)

Again, if the compiler can't guarantee the string's value (because the string is a variable, not a literal or constant), it's not going to be interned. This time, I'll tweak your sample very slightly to demonstrate how we can make the value of `c` a compile-time constant:

```
string a = "test";     // a literal, "test" - always fixed at compile time
const string b = "te"; // a constant - always fixed at compile time
object c = b + "st";   // a constant plus a literal - always fixed at compile time
// c == a is true
```

It's worth noting that there's a compiler warning when you compare `a == c` in your original code: "Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the right hand side to type 'string'." Warnings are worth paying attention to! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine(object.Equals(a, c));

Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(c));

Console.WriteLine(c.Equals(a));
```

work the same way because they're comparing the value of the object, while

```
Console.WriteLine(a == c);
```

compares the reference that a and c have for that value